# Between BV and Baire 2

Tags: real-analysis

My question is about functions of bounded variation (BV) on the reals.

On one hand, [Helly's selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_selection_theorem) provides (fairly restrictive) conditions under which a sequence of BV-functions has a sub-sequence that convergences to a BV-function.

On the other hand, if a sequence of BV-functions converges to some function, then the latter is at most Baire 2.

My question is whether we can significantly improve 'Baire 2' in the previous, e.g. assuming the BV-functions in the sequence are uniformly bounded?

Answer (score 3):

I happened across the following paper:

Charles Tucker, "[Limit of a Sequence of Functions with Only Countably Many Points of Discontinuity](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1968-0219029-3)", Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 19, No. 1 (Feb., 1968), pp. 118- 122, [MR219029](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=219029), [Zbl 0157.20302](https://zbmath.org/0157.20302).

The following theorem (statement at  p. 118, proof from p. 120 to p. 122) expresses that pointwise limits of regulated functions are equal to a Baire 1 function outside of some countable set.

[image]